# Access a container from another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I see other posts but don't work in my case, maybe i'm beeing dumb.

I tried everything.

My last version of Dockerfile:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  bookmemoriesfrontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookmemoriesfrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Frontend\BookMemoriesFrontend\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:443"
    depends_on:
      - booksapi
      - authorsapi

  authorsapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authorsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services\AuthorsAPI\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8002:443"

  booksapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}booksapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services\BooksAPI\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:443"
```

When I open CLI from BookMemoriesFrontend, I tried several curl commmand, when i try :

```
curl Booksapi/api/book
```

I think it will receive the api result and I dont receive nothing in result.

When I run CLI my machine:

```
curl -s https://localhost:8001/api/book
```

It gives the API result.

Please help me, I'm around this almost a week.

Comment: You still need to specify the port when you do `curl`. So you need to do `curl booksapi:8001/api/book` to reach booksapi service

Comment: If you don't use a port it will use the standard HTTP port 80; connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all so port 8001 probably isn't right.  Your host command uses an `https://...` protocol but the container command doesn't; does `curl https://booksapi/api/book` specifying that protocol work?  Does `curl -v ...` give a more informative error?

Comment: When I try: curl https://authorsapi/api/authors                   the result: curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain wa
s issued by an authority that is not trusted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `curl https://booksapi/api/book` or `curl https://booksapi:443/api/book`.

Since it's https, it'll make the request on port 443 by default, which is what the container is listening on, so there's no need to specify a port.

Port 8001 is only used when you access the API from the host machine. When you're on the bridge network that docker-compose creates, you use the container ports directly.

Comment: When I do: `curl -k https://authorsapi/api/authors` with the -k I receive the results but I can't receive in the API because the certificate and I dont know how to add it ´curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain wa
s issued by an authority that is not trusted.´

Comment: That's a bit out of scope for the problem outlined in this question, so I think you should create a new one for that.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.